# Javascript map string lookup. Can't find key even though key is in object

Tags: javascript

I must be missing something pretty standard here.

I have a map mapping string to object. What I write out:

```
console.log(playerMap, this.id(), playerMap[this.id()]);
```

What it prints out:
[image]

this does not make a lot of sense to me since the key seems to be right there.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ct8mpj6L/)

Comment: is `id` a function ?

Comment: I am using knockoutJS and this is just how to abstract a ko.observable. This part must be right since it prints out the string correctly as the second output

Comment: could u share your code in detail , actually it is difficult to know with such data.

Comment: please provide output in text format, not image. Could you create a snippet both defines your variables and performs the output, reproducing the problem?

Comment: no point in making an executable snippet if the snippet doesn't demonstrate  your error

Comment: Without actual code, it is guessing. Here are two potential reasons: (1) `console.log` is not always synchronous, so the playerMap might actually not yet have the property at the moment you execute `playerMap[this.id()]`, and it only gets its value later. `console.log` can be misleading. (2) the function `this.id()` can return different values in different calls.

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ct8mpj6L/
Problem on javascript line 70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your Fiddle, apparently your `playerMap` is not yet initialised when you `new FeedViewModel()`, if you change your console.log to

```
 console.log(Object.keys(playerMap).length, this.id(), playerMap[this.id()]);
```

you will see the object is empty

```
> 0 "123243df6" undefined
```

It's always confused when you console.log object because the object displayed is only resolved when you expand the `>` in the console. It is not the state of the object when you console.log'd the object.

Comment: Ahh okay. That makes sense. Thanks a lot!